# jQuery Mobile: How to create a dropdown menu when an icon is clicked?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

I have an icon in the header. When the icon is clicked, I'd like to show a dropdown menu. When an element of the dropdown menu is clicked, it fires the action but the icon should not be replaced by the selected element. In other words, the icon is always displayed regardless of what's selected from the list. Is there a built-in functionality for this in jQuery Mobile or some other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Have the href for the button refer to the id of a popup div:

```
<a href="#menu" data-role="button" data-rel="popup">Menu</a>
```

Then create a popup div that contains a list:

```
<div id="menu" data-role="popup">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="whatever">selection 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="whatever">selection 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks like a good idea but is there an easy way to control the position of the popup div? By default it positions the popup right on top of the button and it dynamically adds the inline style based on the `data-position-to` attribute. Do you know if there is there a way to style it effectively? I can add a style to `#popupMenu-popup` but if I have multiple popups in the same page, this will have conflicting results. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can style it with data-theme elements, just like any other widget. Not sure what you mean beyond that. Positioning options are detailed [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/popup/).